# invalid result in casting void* to anything

Tags: c++, g++, bison

I cast some thing like `double` to `void*` and pass it to an other function. but in when I want to cast my `void*` to `double` I got wrong result!!! something like 9.18358-e10.

memory address is same in previous function, sizeof `void*` and `double` are same. but result after casting is wrong.

I tried `reinterpret_cast<>` , `static_cast<>` , `memcpy` ,... but nothing happened.

what's wrong?? what should I do?

**Code**

```
void* def_double(double* d){
    void* v = d;
    return v;
}

void print(void* v){
    cout << *((double*) v) << endl;
}
```

note: I use this code in bison to save my variables.

Comment: You cannot cast `double` to `void*` and expect it to not change. You can, however, cast a `double*` to `void*`.

Comment: @scohe001 you are casting a `double*` to a `void*` and then back to a `double*` So of course that is going to work correctly. But that is not what Ashkan is asking for

Comment: @scohe001 "_When I try what you're saying, things look fine_" Well.. It's not entirely what OP is saying.. You cast `double*` to `void*`, while OP is explaining, that he is trying to cast `double` to `void*`.

Comment: @all ahh my fault. Must've misread this one.

Comment: I add code to my post

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve] including the actual and the desired behavior. Also, please explain your underlying goal, i.e. what you really want to achieve on a higher level.

Comment: @AshkanAbd your code example does not match your description. There is a BIG difference between storing a `double` value directly inside a `void*` pointer itself, vs simply passing around a `double*` pointer as a `void*` pointer.  What do you REALLY want to accomplish? You are confusing the issue. Please provide a better code example, and a better explanation of your actual goal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provided that `void*` is at least as large as `double` (which it will be in a 64-bit app, but not in a 32-bit app), then you can use `memcpy()` to store the bits of a `double` value inside the bits of a `void*` pointer, for example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

void doIt(void *p)
{
    double d;
    std::memcpy(&d, &p, sizeof(double));
    std::cout << "After: " << d << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    static_assert(sizeof(void*) >= sizeof(double), "void* is not large enough!");

    double d = 123.45;
    std::cout << "Before: " << d << std::endl;

    void *p = nullptr;
    std::memcpy(&p, &d, sizeof(double));
    doIt(p);

    return 0;
}
```

```
Before: 123.45
After: 123.45
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/DnGSVo)

Comment: Ok, but: Why would you ever do this? Especially as an apparent beginner.

Comment: @AshkanAbd the provided demo link proves that it does work.

Comment: @BaummitAugen for example, think of a 3rd party library that works with callback functions, passing user-defined data around using `void*` pointers. You could certainly `new` a `double` in dynamic memory and pass that around, but then you'd have to `delete` it at some point. On the other hand, if `void*` has enough bits, you can just stuff the `double` bits directly into the `void*` itself and avoid `new`/`delete`.